# PostgreSQL PSQL SELECT into a variable

Tags: postgresql, variables, psql

On the Postgres console (PSQL) I try to write a simple 'batch' test:

```
\set oid

\set username 'john'
\set emailadr 'john@mailbox.net'
\set password 'jjjj'
INSERT INTO :oid SELECT auc_user_insert(:'username', :'emailadr', :'password');
SELECT auc_user_select(:oid);
SELECT auc_user_delete(:oid);
```

`auc_user_insert`, `auc_user_select` and `auc_user_delete` are application specific Postgres functions and work fine for each self (within the Query Tool). 
The `insert` Function returns a bigint as unique id, which I would like to assign to the variable `oid` for usage in the next lines.

But in PSQL for the `INTO :oid` statement I get the error

```
ERROR:  Relation 'bigint' doesn't exist
```

What's wrong and what would be the right way to work with such a variable? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the `INSERT INTO` is meant to affect the `:oid` variable rather than inserting the result of a select into a table, you want this instead:

```
SELECT auc_user_insert(:'username', :'emailadr', :'password') AS oid;
\gset
SELECT auc_user_select(:oid);
SELECT auc_user_delete(:oid);
```

`\gset` is a new meta-command since psql 9.3

If you have an older version, it's much harder to emulate this.

Description from the manpage:

> \gset [ prefix ]
>
> Sends the current query input buffer to the server and stores the query's output into psql variables (see Variables). The query to be
>   executed must return exactly one row. Each column of the row is stored
>   into a separate variable, named the same as the column